# How to get image resource name

Tags: android

How do I get an imageview resource name which has been set dynamically?

This is the image Adapter code:

```
  public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private Context mContext;

  public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
  }

  public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
  }

  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
  }

  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
  }

  // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;

    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
      // attributes

      LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
      v = li.inflate(R.layout.gridxml, null);
        imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);

      imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
      //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
      imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    } else {
      imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
  }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setTag(mThumbIds[position]);

    System.out.println(mThumbIds[0]);
          System.out.println(mThumbIds[1]);
          System.out.println(mThumbIds[2]);
          System.out.println(mThumbIds[3]);
          System.out.println(mThumbIds[4]);
    return imageView;
  }

  // references to our images
  private Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.directory_xml,
      R.drawable.news_xml, R.drawable.calendar_xml,
      R.drawable.facilities_xml, R.drawable.employee_handbook_xml,R.drawable.settings_xml };
}
}
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by 'set dynamically'?

Comment: can you elaborate your question ?

Answer (score 6):

you can use `setTag()` and `getTag()` to set or get image resource name along with imgae

when you are setting image dynamically you can add the following line to set imageresource name with the image

```
imageView.setTag("image resource name");
```

if you want to retrieve image resource name you can use

```
String imageName = (String) imageView.getTag();
```

Comment: Actually sir i have used grid view in which only one imageview is used and set diffrent image on using imageadapter class so how can i get name of the drawable

Comment: you are setting image resource id which is integer so you getTag() will return you that integer. you can get drawable object by passing that integer value to getResources().getDrawable(id)  but not name of that image

Comment: what to put in "getResources().getDrawable(id)" id  and when i replace the id with R.id.imagview  i m getting the force close

Comment: try with the following code  Integer id = (Integer) imageView.getTag();
    getResources().getDrawable(id);

Comment: but in the previous solution which u have given what i have to give in getDrawable(id) "id"

Comment: the same that i have written now

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. This code works fine for me.

```
String resName = getResourceNameFromClassByID(R.drawable.class, R.drawable.imagename);
```

and the method is

```
public String getResourceNameFromClassByID(Class<?> aClass, int resourceID) 
                    throws IllegalArgumentException{
    /* Get all Fields from the class passed. */
    Field[] drawableFields = aClass.getFields();

    /* Loop through all Fields. */
    for(Field f : drawableFields){
        try {
            /* All fields within the subclasses of R 
             * are Integers, so we need no type-check here. */

            /* Compare to the resourceID we are searching. */
            if (resourceID == f.getInt(null))
                return f.getName(); // Return the name.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /* Throw Exception if nothing was found*/
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

for more details , you can refer to  http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?t=506

Comment: link is broken or a spam!

Comment: what is the import of Field ?  incomplete answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this

```
String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(image[position]);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ImageView imgvw = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

imgvw.setTag("name");

String strImgName = (String) imgvw.getTag();
```

Comment: How does that return the resource set on the ImageView?

Comment: This would only give the tag name which you have set here imgvw.setTag("name"); so how to get image or resource name.