# I have few imageview in activity_A and when i click a image in activity_A it should be opend in activity_B how?

Tags: android

Sir/Madam/Friends,

I am new to android program, I created one Linear layout in this activity I put 20 images, and when i click one image that particular image will open in another activity,in second activity i put only one Image view. So please how to do that?.

i did but my programe will showing only one same image only every time.

```
//this is the first activity.
public class abcd extends ActionBarActivity{

public final static String VIEW_ID = "name";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.abcd);

}



public void click(View view)
{

   String iname=getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId());
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,abcd_disp.class);

    intent.putExtra("VIEW_ID", x);

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

//this is the second activity

```
public class abcd_disp extends ActionBarActivity {
ImageView imageView;
int[] im=new int[]{
  R.mipmap.a,R.mipmap.b
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String vidname=(String)intent.getStringExtra(abcd.VIEW_ID);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_abcd_disp);

    if(vidname=="aa"){
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_abcd_disp);
        imageView.setImageResource(im[0]);

    }
else
    {
 imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_abcd_disp);
            imageView.setImageResource(im[1]);
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is:

Suppose you have a set of images in drawable folder with which you are populating ImageView's in your **Activity A** .

Let the images be *@drawable/image1, @drawable/image2, @drawable/image3, @drawable/image4*

So once you click on the particular ImageView, you can retrieve image resource name as

`imageView.getTag();`

But this returns an object. So type cast it to String. This is done to pass it along with intent, since object cannot be passed directly without serializing or parceble.

```
String imageResourceName = (String)imageView.getTag();
```

Once you have this, pass this along with the Intent you are going to startActivity() with.

```
intent.putExtra("resource_name", imageResourceName);
startActivity(intent);
```

So in **Activity B**, where there is a ImageView, you set the image src in ImageView using

imageView.setTag(getIntent().getStringExtra("resource_name"));

[Further information of setting image using setTag()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449654/how-to-get-image-resource-name)

Answer (score 0):

Use Fragment instead of the Activity!